# What does "once removed either way" mean?

Tags: meaning, j-r-r-tolkien, the-lord-of-the-rings

From Book I Chapter 1 of *The Fellowship of the Ring* by J. R. R. Tolkien:

> Mr. Drogo married poor Miss Primula Brandybuck. She was our Mr. Bilbo's first cousin on the mother's side (her mother being the youngest of the Old Took's daughters); and Mr. Drogo was his second cousin. So Mr. Frodo is his first and second cousin, **once removed either way**, as the saying is, if you follow me.

What is the meaning of the phrase in bold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

‘Either way’ modifies ‘first and second cousin’, so that

> first and second cousin, once removed either way

means

> first cousin, once removed, and second cousin, once removed

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin#Removed) for an explanation of the relationship terminology.

There are Baggins, Took and Brandybuck family trees in Appendix C of *The Return of the King*, which allow us to confirm this passage as follows:

1. Frodo and Bilbo are first cousins, once removed, on their mothers’ sides, because Bilbo’s mother Belladonna *née* Took was sister of Frodo’s grandmother Mirabella *née* Took. (Their father Gerontius was known as ‘the Old Took’.)

   [image]
2. Frodo and Bilbo are second cousins, once removed, on their fathers’ sides, because Bilbo’s grandfather Mungo was brother of Frodo’s great-grandfather Largo.

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you and X are first cousins.

X has a child, Y. You and Y are still "first cousins," but Y is one (generation) removed from X (in a downward direction). If you had a child, Z, Y and Z would be second cousins, both of them being children of two first cousins.

X also has a parent, A, who is a sibling of one of your parents, B. At this stage, A would be your uncle or aunt. But A is "once removed" from your first cousin, X, in an upward direction.

The "higher" of two generations controls, so A would be "avuncular" (root word, uncle) to you, not your "first cousin once removed." And you and Y would be "first cousins" once removed, not "second cousins" once removed, even though Y would be a "second cousin" to your child Z.